# Concatenation of SQL 1 to many tables

Tags: sql, concatenation

My apologies if this has already been covered, I just could not find a suitable answer. If anyone know of one, please do let me know.

I wrote a quick tool to take all the fields in the second table and concatenate them, then update the AddtionalTripLineInfo field in the first table. it was fairly quick, however, my question is, is there an easier straight with a SQL query to do this and make the formatting the same?

I'm using SQL Server and it doesn't matter if this is not looking right or formatting, this is the job I was dealt and that is the format they want.

[image: Table2 to concat Table1]

thank you in advance!

Comment: Please simplify the example into a few columns at most, so it's easy for us to understand what you need.

Comment: My apologies, I changed it to two columns. The first table is what I would like to have happen. thank you!

Comment: MySQL5.x? MySQL 8? SQLite? MS SQL Server? PostgreSQL? Oracle? Etc, Etc...  And why such bespoke encoding? Why not JSON or XML or Anything ***standard***? *(For that matter, why do this at all?)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your image I'm going to guess you're using `SQL Server`, if so...

- `CONCAT()` will combine the `SeqNo` and the `Distance`
- `STRING_AGG()` will combine the rows

```
SELECT
  TripID,
  STRING_AGG(
    CONCAT(SeqNo, '|', ThruWayDistanceCalculated),
    '~'
  ) WITHIN GROUP (
      ORDER BY SeqNo
    )
FROM
  example
GROUP BY
  TripID
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c18456392ee5a242d45a945a8aaadbb2

Comment: Thank you Mat! this is exactly what I'm looking for... just to find the flipping company is running on a 2016 sql server and STRING_AGG and other functions are not included in those. I do appreciate this and will keep it handy .